# when did cast in c++ occur, compile time or run time?

Tags: c++, casting

c++ implicit cast/conversion happens at compile time or run time?

```cpp
int64 i64 = 1;
int8 i8 = static_cast<int8>(i64); // (1) explicit cast, when does this happen?
int32 i32 = i8; // (2) implicit cast,when does this happen?
```

**Duplicate**
this question is duplicate with other question, please see follow:

[1] [Do constant and reinterpret cast happen at compile time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27309604/do-constant-and-reinterpret-cast-happen-at-compile-time/27309763)

[2][Is static_cast<T>(...) compile-time or run-time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18454669/is-static-castt-compile-time-or-run-time)

Comment: "It depends".  In general, Static_cast: would be compile time.  But, for example, static_cast<std::string>("Hello") ends up calling std::string constructor.  Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18454669/

Comment: The conversion can't happen before the value that needs converting is known.

Comment: @molbdnilo So, it happens at run time?

Comment: @maidamai As the first comment says, it depends. In some cases, code is generated to convert one value into another. If the value to be converted is known at compile time, the compiler may perform the conversion immediately. It may also be the case that the conversion does nothing at all, so whether it "happens" at all is a philosphical question. In your example, the compiler would most likely generate the equivalent of `int 64 i64 = 1; int8 i8 = 1; int32 i32 = 1;`.

Comment: About terminology: a **cast** is something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a **conversion**. In some contexts, various conversions can be done implicitly; some conversions won't be done unless you tell the compiler to with a cast. There is no such thing as an "implicit cast".

Comment: A **cast** is always a compile-time thing; it tells the compiler to do a conversion. Some conversions don't require any code; the compiler just pretends that the bit pattern has a different type. Others require adjusting the bits to match the new type. In the first case, you might say that the conversion is done at compile time; in the second, it's done at runtime.